# TYPO3, simple user interface in backend

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-tca

I would like to have a simple interface in TYPO3 backend for viewing the data from database (joining two tables) and also to be able to edit the data.
I tired something with tca array but I dont know how display the data that are already in database.
Is there an option that says foe example that this TCA configuration should display the data in this list?+
Or any other option?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one ain't to bad either: mh_omsqlio

It gives you a listview of you records (single table) that you can edit in frontend. Database relations can be displayed if you read the maual.

With joins you can not update in the frontend.

Super fast way to build mockup for frontend plugins.

BR. Anders

Answer (score -2):

Another option is the Typo3 extension phpMyAdmin

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote but phpmyadmin is not recommended within a TYPO3 environment due to security concerns and as it's not specific enough for this question.